# Can't Float Input Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

today I build a contact section of my website, but I tried to float it and when the inputs where floated they did not work, they where not clickable. Is there a reason that it is not working?

I read online that it may be because it is below another element so i put `z-index: 999;` but that did not help either.

What I am trying to do is get the name and email boxes onto the same line, with messages below.

Here is my code:

```js
<? php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'versionabstracts@gmail.com'; //<-----Put Your email address here.
if (empty($_POST['name']) ||
  empty($_POST['email']) ||
  empty($_POST['message'])) {
  $errors. = "\n Error: All fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if (!preg_match(
  "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
  $email_address)) {
  $errors. = "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if (empty($errors)) {
  $to = $myemail;
  $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
  $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
  " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message";

  $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
  $headers. = "Reply-To: $email_address";

  mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
  //redirect to the 'thank you' page
  header('Location: index.html');
} ?>
< !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < title > Error! < /title>
</head >

  < body >
  <!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
  <? php
echo nl2br($errors); ?>


< /body>
</html >
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

#contactbg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 1670px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 286px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1650px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 290px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1570px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 295px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1550px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 340px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1530px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 346px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 358px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1470px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 364px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1440px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 388px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1370px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 416px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1345px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1350px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 466px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1280px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 485px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1260px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 510px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1270px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1280px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1770px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 556px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1700px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 566px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1630px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 580px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1550px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 624px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1530px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1540px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 671px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1520px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 692px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1450px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 775px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1350px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1360px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 917px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1340px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 931px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1290px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1122px) {
  #contactbg {
    top: 1200px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #contactbg h4 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  #name {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  #email {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1999;
  }
  #message,
  textarea {
    width: 80%;
  }
  #message {
    position: relative;
  }
  #submit {} .button-primary {
    position: relative;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  textarea {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #name {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
  }
  #email {
    position: relative;
    right: 100px;
  }
  textarea {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #name {
    left: 150px;
  }
  #email {
    right: 150px;
  }
  textarea {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
#name,
#email,
#message {
  z-index: 10000;
}
#submit,
.button-primary {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
textarea {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div id="contactbg">
  <div class="container4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="animated">
        <div class="twelve columns">
          <h4 id="contact">Get In Touch!</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
          <div class="animated">
            <p id="name">
              <label for='name'>Your Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated">
            <p id="email">
              <label for='email'>Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated">
            <p id="message">
              <label for='message'>Message</label>
              <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="submit" class="animated">
            <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>

        <script language="JavaScript">
          // Code for validating the form
           // Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
           // for details
          var frmvalidator = new Validator("contactform");
          frmvalidator.addValidation("name", "req", "Please provide your name");
          frmvalidator.addValidation("email", "req", "Please provide your email");
          frmvalidator.addValidation("email", "email", "Please enter a valid email address");
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is all that code needed to replicate the problem? Please try to reduce the code to just enough to reproducing the problem. Just doing that may lead you to the solution. On a side not your labels are semantically broken, the `for=''` attribute should be pointing to an `id` attribute on an input element, not a `p` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my problem, I was floating the inputs to the same line but one input was `width:100%;` so it was covering the other, I just gave the inputs both a width of 44% and I was good!

Answer (score 0):

In the form, add a class to the parent divs of the inputs you want and style those div classes with display: inline-block

```
<div class="animated name">
    <p id="name">
        <label for='name'>Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
   </p>
</div>
<div class="animated email">
    <p id="email">
        <label for='email'>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </p>
</div>
```

And in the CSS:

```
.name, .email {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="contactbg">
  <div class="container4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="animated_1">
        <div class="twelve columns">
          <h4 id="contact">Get In Touch!</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <form method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php">
          <div class="animated">
            <p class="fl">
              <label for='name'>Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated">
            <p class="fl">
              <label for='email'>Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated">
            <p class="fl">
              <label for='message'>Message</label>
              <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="fd" class="animated">
            <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </form>
```

CSS

```
label { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ECECEC;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 180px;
    height: 25px;
    color:#bababa;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.fd{

    width: 180px;
}
.fd, .fl{ 
    float: left; 
    margin-bottom:15px;
 }
.fd {
  width: 396px !important;
}
```

> Hope this will be fine